# How would I go about developing a program that automatically sends an email with the tracking number to a customer using EasyPost API?

Tags: e-commerce, webflow, easypost

I'm a fairly new web developer and I have an ecommerce website that integrates [EasyPost](https://www.easypost.com/) to create and print shipping labels.

EasyPost has an API. Also, in each shipping label, I see a JavaScript object (I think) that displays  `buyer_address... "email": "example@gmail.com",`, which tells me that the email information is there.

My question is somewhat general in scope: What steps would I need to take to go about creating this automation? The website is built in Webflow, so I don't really have a "codebase" or "repository" to store whatever code is needed to build the automation.

Since the buyer email is making it into EasyPost with integrations already in place, I feel that I could create a simple program that emails the tracking number to the buyer email every time a label is generated, or perhaps when package is shipped, without the program needing to interact with Webflow or other integrations.

I attempted using Zapier, as well as Make.com. Neither worked, and OrderDesk doesn't have a way to send tracking number emails.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Webflow has some kind of support for Webhooks (https://webflow.com/feature/create-webhooks-from-project-settings). EasyPost offers webhooks for free as an add-on service. Basically, with webhooks, EasyPost would send tracking events to Webflow proactively, but Webflow (or you) would need to manage the logic for what to do with those tracking events after they are delivered.

[EasyPost Webhook Guide](https://www.easypost.com/webhooks-guide)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any off the shelf products that could do this for you without writing any code. We have a guide that details how you might accomplish this with Ruby (you could then follow this as an example for any other language): https://www.easypost.com/email-tracking-tutorial

A few suggestions:

1. Integrate something into `Webflow` if possible (I'm unfamiliar with the platform so couldn't say).
2. Build a simple script that runs on a schedule (cronjob) that retrieves your trackers from EasyPost and sends an email to customers if they have not yet received one. To your point, this approach wouldn't require interacting with `Webflow` at all and could be done with some local code running on a server and just your EasyPost API key.
3. I've created a simple UI for EasyPost: https://github.com/Justintime50/easypost-tools-ui, it could be interesting to add this particular use-case as a feature to that project. If you're interested, feel free to open an issue on GitHub for the repo listed here and I'd consider it.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use easypost's API webhooks, to detect when shipment tracking information is provided, or package information is updated.

https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#trackers

It looks like it has a lot of states, so you can keep the client updated regarding the package status from the moment the tracking # is assigned;

```
EZ1000000001    pre_transit
EZ2000000002    in_transit
EZ3000000003    out_for_delivery
EZ4000000004    delivered
EZ5000000005    return_to_sender
EZ6000000006    failure
EZ7000000007    unknown
```

You can install webhooks from [these docs](https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#webhooks).

To send the email, you can use an automation service e.g. Make to capture those webhook events, and then compose and send an email to that customer. I like MailJet for that purpose, because it has excellent template support and you can send from your own company domain. But there are many email-sending options.

A bigger challenge, maybe, is getting the email address to send to. I didn't spot it glancing through the Trackers or Shipments data structures, and I am primarily seeing physical address info.

If EasyPost is not tracking the customer's email with the shipment, you may have some challenge in that you'd need to capture the client info through Webflow's order webhooks, and then associate that with EasyPost's shipmentid, and store those in a reference table.

Many automation services offer database-like functionality for this purpose, or you could use e.g. google sheets ( columns webflow OrderID, easypost ShipmentID, customer Email ) or airtable for that purpose.

But you'd have to look into the Easypost integration as well, and you may need to make that integration manual so that you can acquire all 3 of those pieces of information at the same point in your business data flow.